# How can i concatenate two CNN models which each have a different input

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, concatenation, classification, tf.keras

I want to do a concatenated model for binary classification,

the data_set is the same, but in the first model I did some preprocessing to the image,

the input is x*train and ytrain  for the training, and xval,  y*val for validation

the  input shape is 224,224,1.

in the second model, I used the image as it was with the function

train_set= tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory

val_set= tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory

the input shape is 224,224,3

I want to merge or concatenate them both, but I don't know how to fit the model for the training and validation with the different inputs

I want to merge or concatenate them both, but I don't know how to fit the model for the training and validation with the different inputs.

if anyone can help me I would be grateful

Thanks

Comment: You can use there keras layer.concatenate([ layer1, layer2 ], axis=-1). This way you stack the inputs on top of each other, 224x224x1 with 224x224x3 would become 224x224x4.

Comment: If your plan was to merge the two whole models into one model, that is going to be tough. You can extract the weights from the trained models and apply them to a new model that has the same shape. An alternative would be to keep both models, and concatenate their output like mentioned in my previous comment and feed the concatenated output into a new mode.

Comment: A model can have multiple inputs. Or, you can have 224x224x3 as input and do the preprocessing within the model

Comment: @BasvanderLinden effectively, I want to concatenate their output, the problem is how to fit the model concatenated with those different inputs, should I train each model separately before that?